# Работаю в Windows Forms c#

Tags: c#

Есть кнопка и текстбокс, нужно что бы при нажатии на кнопку, начинался ввод в текстбокс. Как это можно сделать? Не нашел нужной обработки события

Comment: "начинался ввод в текстбокс" - что это значит? `this.ActiveControl = TextBox1;`?

Comment: когда мы просто кликнем на текстбокс - туда можно будет что -то вводить. Вот это мне и нужно, кликнули на клетку - а дальше вводим что-то

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.ActiveControl = TextBox1;
```

Comment: cпасибо большое)

Comment: @user351599 Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: можно тебе еще один вопрос?